# Printing random number of words per line

Tags: python

I'm just trying to write a simple script that prints between 1 and 10 words per line from a source. I know this should be super simple but I'm having a brain fart. This is my best guess:

```
import random

s = open("somefile.txt").readlines()

for line in s:
    line.strip()
    rand_int = rand.randint(1,10)
    sentence = ''.join(s,rand_int)
    print sentence
```

Specifically, I'm just having trouble figuring out how to tell python print a random group of words a random number of times per line. Is this something a list comprehension might help with?

I'd appreciate any help you could give. Thank you!

Comment: By random group of words, do you mean words from one line of your source?

Comment: At this point I don't care if its gibberish, I just mean splitting the file into words (which I just realized I did not include in my code) and then printing a random number(1,10) of words on each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import random

with open("somefile.txt", "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        print ' '.join(random.sample(line.strip().split(), random.randint(1, 10)))
```

Here is a portion of the documentation of [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

> random.sample(*population*, *k*)
>       Return a *k* length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

So we can create `population` by splitting the line on whitespace, and then randomize `k`, which should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question :) Mind if I merge this change into my own answer?